# Stacked font awesome icons with transparent middle?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Is there anyway to have stacked font awesome icons have a transparent middle or borders? Like in this picture? Would love any help because I am totally stumped. here is an image of what I am going for. Plus my code.
[image]

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x cool-span">
                      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background4"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x icon-background6"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x"></i>
                </span>
```

Comment: It looks like Gedy Rivera Social might have what you want https://css-tricks.com/flat-icons-icon-fonts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet to replicate that effect using stacked font-awesome icons is going to be to use css `mix-blend-mode` which will allow a child element to effectively 'cut' through the parent when set to `hard-light`.

I've adapted the fiddle from AWolf to use this technique, positioning is a little fiddly and potentially hacky but someone might know a better way to stack the icons as parent and child

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0hftugox/3/

Answer (score 2):

Please check if this will work for you, setting its opacity will make it transparent;

```
.fa.fa-heart { opacity : 0.1;  } /* Change the value to suit your need */
```

or use rgba to set transparency

```
 .fa.fa-heart { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
```

Comment: Yes, opacity is a good way to adjust the transparency but I think it's difficult to make the effect like in the image. 100% transparent heart - looks a bit like a boolean subtraction (don't know if that's possible in css). Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0hftugox/).

Comment: Tried that but the heart is stacked on top of a circle, therefore once transparent its just a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [iconmoon](https://icomoon.io/app) site, select the Font-awesome library then edit/add the heart icon as you wish and regenerate the library. It's the fast solution and without doing any CSS tricks